# VS Code Ctrl+C has a wrong behaviour

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when i try to use Ctrl+C to copy something, it changes the insert mode instead. There is a blue bar at the bottom of the screen, with all the informations about the file (python interpreter, number of line and column of the cursor, ...) and `-INSERT-` . When I press Ctrl+C, the `-INSERT-` switches to `-NORMAL-` and I can't copy what I highlighted.

Comment: You have some extension installed.

Comment: You might have the VSCodeVim extension installed: [VS code VIM extension copy and paste](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58306002/2745495)

Answer (score 13):

I too had this issue. Resolved was by **disabling** the **VIM** extension or you can **uninstall** it too.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this person probably wants the extension and is familiar with it. Removing the extension is not automatically a solution for most people who use it. Instead, a question like [VS code VIM extension copy and paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306002/vs-code-vim-extension-copy-and-paste) might yield a good answer for those people.

Comment: Thank you mate! I completely forgot that I have installed that extension and I would never guess that it is the reason behind this behavior

Answer (score 2):

i also faced the same issue

**I SOLVED IT BY**

1 Disabling vim extension,

2 Uninstall vim extension in vscode